# Multiple threads and boost's io_service

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Boost's [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) says: it is important to give the `io_service` some work to do before calling `boost::asio::io_service::run()`. But what happen if I give some work to do and my `io_service` object run method is running onto multiple threads? Should I give 1 work per thread, to prevent others to finish? Or I may start io's run on many threads and give only 1 work to do. I wish to mention, the word 'work' in my question DOES NOT refer to `io_service::work::work`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `io_service`'s work state is not determined by the amount of threads processing the `io_service`.  For example, if an `io_service` has work, all threads processing the `io_service` via [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) will remain blocked processing the event loop, even if the amount of threads is greater than the amount of posted work.  Therefore, it is safe to add a single work operation to an `io_service`, then have many threads process the `io_service`.

Overall, unless concurrency is specifically hinted in the `io_service` constructor, the `io_service` does not make a distinction between its event loop being processed by a single thread or multiple threads.  As noted in the [threads overview](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html), an `io_service` will treat all threads that have joined its pool as being equivalent, distributing work across threads in an arbitrary fashion.